# Set relation inside items.create or items.update hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, directus

I use Directus 10.6.2 and I'm currently working on a hook extension where I want to do some data wrangling when importing data via CSV. When importing items in my `products` collection I want to allow a special column in my CSV that holds the name of the products category. So I can take this value while importing and check if I can find an item by that name in the related `categories` collection or if not create a new one. This actually works already but what I can't get to work is creating the relation in the `products` collection. When I extend the input in the respective filter for example like `input.categories = [4]` after I find the category or created a new one I always get a `FORBIDDEN` error.

```
const CATEGORY_NAME_KEY = 'category:name';

filter('products.items.create', async (
    input: Partial<Product> | any,
    { collection }: { collection: string },
    { schema }: { schema: object }
) => {
    const categoriesCollection = new ItemsService('categories', { schema });

    try {
        const [ existingCategory ] = await categoriesCollection.readByQuery({ filter: {
            name: input[CATEGORY_NAME_KEY],
        }});
        
        if (existingCategory?.id) {
            input.categories = [ existingCategory.id ]; // This throws FORBIDDEN error
        } else {
            const newCategoryID = await categoriesCollection.createOne({
                name: input[CATEGORY_NAME_KEY],
            });
            
            input.categories = [ newCategoryID ]; // This throws FORBIDDEN error
        }
    } catch(error) {
        logger.error(error);
    }

    return input;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a working solution eventhough I'm not sure if thats the intended way but to me it look reasonable.

After trying a lot of different things I realized I cannot do this by manipulating the input for the product item but rather create a new entry in the junction collection and that was relatively straight forward. As I needed also the product ID for that I had to wait until the product was actually created so I moved the logic into an `action` rather than a `filter`.

```
action('products.items.create', async (
    { key, payload },
    { schema }: { schema: object }
) => {
    const productsCategoriesCollection = new ItemsService('products_categories', { schema });

    await productsCategoriesCollection.createOne({
        products_id: key,
        categories_id: payload.newCategoryID,
    });
})
```

I created the category before in the `filter` hook like you can see in my question above and saved it there in `input.newCategoryID` temporarely to reuse it in the `action` afterwards through `payload.newCategoryID`.